# Django Translation appears to not be using translations

Tags: django, django-templates, django-i18n

I am trying to set-up template translation inside of Django templates and I am bit puzzled by why it's not working. I've followed the docs but I imagine I am missing one small thing that is tripping this up.

I've done the following:

- `USE_I18N = True`
- `LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale/'),)`
- `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'`
- `LANGUAGES = [('en-us', _('English - US')), ('zh-hans', _('简体中文')), ('es', _('Spanish'))]`
- Added `{% load i18n %}` to the top of the templates
- Added `{% trans %}` tags into the templates like this: `<a href="{% url 'about-us' %}">{% trans 'About' %}</a>`
- Ran `./manage.py makemessages -l es` and got the .po file in the locale path so I know it's finding all the template tags.
- Ran `./manage.py compilemessages` and got the .mo file in the locale path

I added these two lines to a template to make sure the language code was being set.

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}

<h2>Current Language Code: {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}</h2>
```

I am then able to see that the correct language code is being set.

I am also using this tutorial's template to set the language:
http://joaoventura.net/blog/2016/django-translation-4/

With that I know a translation is being applied because the selection menu in the form updates the language (in the code side).  I assume this is using locale files inside the i18n app.

I also noticed that it is picking up translations properly inside the admin interface.

I'm using Django 1.11.6 on OS X 12.12.6 with Python 3.6.3.

What I am puzzled with is, what could I still be missing?

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include the markup in your template, specifically the text that you're expecting to see translated?

Comment: Updated it with this: `<a href="{% url 'about-us' %}">{% trans 'About' %}</a>` as an example.  The 'makemessages' command does find the tag to generate the .po file.

Comment: OK, it looks like the problem is tied to the Simplified Chinese translation as I've got things translating correctly in Spanish.  I am starting to think it's tied to UTF-8 and Chinese Characters.

Comment: so you have empty .po file?

Comment: I have a full .po file in the correct path. Spanish works but Simplified Chinese does not.

Comment: I updated it to include Simplified Chinese in the description. `('zh-hans', _('简体中文'))`